# How to target DATEDIFF alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

Edit: Based on the answers I have updated my question.

I am using SQL Server. I want to filter the rows so I need to compare two DATEDIFF functions.

Is there a way to target a DATEDIFF function alias in the statement?

For example:

```
SELECT col1, col2, DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol1, datecol2) as 'MyDate'
FROM table1
WHERE MyDate > 0
```

EDIT: Based on the answers, this would be my statement now that works:

```
SELECT col1, col2, DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol1, datecol2) as 'MyDate', DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol2, datecol3) as 'FinalDate'
FROM table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol2, datecol3) > DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol1, datecol2)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "target"?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in this case you will either have to repeat the `DATEDIFF` call in the `WHERE` clause, or use a subquery.  Going with the former:

```
SELECT col1, col2, DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol1, datecol2) AS MyDate
FROM table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol1, datecol2) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want to filter rows according to the expression computed in the `SELECT` clause. You can do this using a table expression to *materialize* the column.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT col1, col2, DATEDIFF(DAY, datecol1, datecol2) as 'MyDate'
  FROM table1
) x
WHERE MyDate > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias in the `where` corresponding to the `select` where it is defined.  Your code appears to be SQL Server, so you can use a lateral join to define the value.  Then you can use it:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, v.MyDate
FROM table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.datecol1, t1.datecol2)) v(MyDate)
WHERE v.MyDate > 0;
```

In this case, though, I would simply recommend:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t1.col2, v.MyDate
FROM table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (DATEDIFF(DAY, t1.datecol1, t1.datecol2)) v(MyDate)
WHERE t1.datecol2 > t1.datecol1;
```

If the two columns are dates, this should be the same -- and it is more readable.